# How to expand inner product square?

Tags: linear-algebra, machine-learning

How does this $||x-x'||$ expand to the equation below?

$\|x-x'\|^2 = (x^T)x + (x')^T x' - 2x^T x'$

Comment: By definition, $$\|x-x'\|=\sqrt{(x-x')^2}.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the fact that the inner product is a **bilinear symmetric form** we get

$$||x-x'||^2=\langle x-x',x-x'\rangle=\langle x,x\rangle-\langle x,x'\rangle-\langle x',x\rangle+\langle x',x'\rangle\\=\langle x,x\rangle-2\langle x,x'\rangle+\langle x',x'\rangle$$

Comment: so then, $<x,x> = x^Tx$ ? But how does $2<x,x'> = 2x^Tx'$ ?

Comment: We have
$$\langle x,x'\rangle =x^Tx'$$
and
$$\langle x,x\rangle=x^Tx=||x||^2$$

Answer (score 2):

Once you know that $\|u\|^2 = \langle u, u \rangle = u^tu $ is the inner product, it's pretty straightforward: apply the distributive law a few times, using $u = x - x'$.